# How can I Give css style to the current menu?

Tags: css

what is the css of current link like when somebody goes to ABOUT US page then about us color changed to red.... then going to CONTACT US page then about us color change to default and CONTACT US color change to red....

please help i am new designer......

Comment: hi you can used active class ..

Answer (score 0):

use :hover in css

replace li in example with whatever element you use in your actual code

eg.

```
li:hover{backgroundcolor:Red;}
```

li tag in case you design menu like

```
<ul>
   <li> Menu1</li>
   <li> Menu2</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Its a mouse over css i know about this i want to know when on current link css like somebody open home page then HOME menu color change to RED.....

Answer (score 0):

Whwn you click on specific menu, that perticular page will be open.
then just do simple thing,

write class for active.

apply this, for home page

for About Us page active class attribute to About Us li

```
<ul>
   <li class="active">Home</li>
   <li>Projects</li>
   <li>About Us</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use JUST CSS to determine which page your user currently is - it just won't do it. You have to adjust your markup to add a hook of some kind that your CSS can use. Like so -

```
<ul id="nav">
   <li><a href="about.html" class="here">About Us</a></li>
   <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

If you're building a static HTML site, you can manually change the HTML on each page to reflect the current page in the menu.

If you're building something more complex, you will probably need to rely on PHP or JavaScript to figure out the current page. This script is a little old (it's from Jeremy Keith's "DOM Scripting"), but it will do the job:

```
function highlightPage(id){
    //make sure DOM methods are understood
    if(!document.getElementsByTagName) return false;
    if(!document.getElementById) return false;
    if(!document.getElementById(id)) return false;
    var nav = document.getElementById(id);
    var links = nav.getElementsByTagName('a');
    for (var i=0; i < links.length; i++){
        var linkurl = links[i].getAttribute('href');
        var currenturl = window.location.href;
        //indexOf will return -1 on non-matches, so we're checking for a positive match
        if (currenturl.indexOf(linkurl) != -1) {
            links[i].className = "here";
            var linktext = links[i].lastChild.nodeValue.toLowerCase();
            document.body.setAttribute("id",linktext);
        }
    }
}

addLoadEvent(function(){
    highlightPage('nav');
    });

function addLoadEvent(func){
    var oldonload = window.onload;
    if (typeof window.onload != 'function') {
        window.onload = func;
    } else {
        window.onload = function(){
            oldonload();
            func();
        }
    }
}
```

This script would go in an [externally linked javascript file](http://www.quackit.com/javascript/tutorial/external_javascript_file.cfm).

Comment: I want this on my all 8 links like menu , about us, contact us, products..etc....

Comment: That's what this script does - it adds the class "here" to the nav item that matches the current window path, dynamically. It's not the best idea to rely on JavaScript for this kind of thing, but it does work.

Answer (score 0):

Give the body an id name `<body id="about-us">`. Your link needs an id, too `<a href="#" id='this-link">`. Then:

```
#about-us #this-link {
color:red;
}  
#contact-us #this-link {
}
```